# How to use value of a variable in ObjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c, variables

I just start to learn ObjectiveC and I have a problem.

I have a variable in a for loop , this variable change value at any iteration and I want get his value.

Here my problem the variable is "name":

for 1st iteration name='id'
for 2nd iteration name='city' ...

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
name = ivar_getName(ivars[i]);
encode = ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivars[i]);
type = decode_type_string(encode);
if (strncmp(encode, "@", 1) == 0)
{
printf(" '%s', ", [[obj name*]UTF8String]);
}
else
{
printf(" %s ", name);
}
}
```

My goal is that the variable is interpreted by its value. if in my iiteration variable name is set to "ID" I want to have: [obj name] => [id obj] (for the id of my instance) if in my iiteration variable name is set to "City" I want to have: [obj name] => [obj City] (for the city of my instance) 
(sorry for my english)

Comment: what are you trying to do?? what do mean by "use"? can you show the code for the for loop

Comment: I give an object to a function, this function give me all attributes stocked in "name" variable (for loop) and their type stocked in another variable (INTROSPECTION)
Here obj is an object and I want use getter/setter to print value of each attribute. [obj name]

Comment: could you show show more of your code?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    name = ivar_getName(ivars[i]);
    encode = ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivars[i]);
    type = decode_type_string(encode);
    if (strncmp(encode, "@", 1) == 0)
    {
    printf(" '%s', ", [[obj name*]UTF8String]);
    }
    else
    {
    printf(" %s ", name);
    }
    }

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you want to do this.

Comment: I want give an instance of object to a function on this function return to me the value of all attributes.

Comment: To what end?  What do you intend to do with the results?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are badly confused about several things. First off, NSString objects do not begin with "@" as the first character of the string. Rather, the "@" character is used to differentiate between a C string literal (eg, "abc") and an Objective-C NSString literal (eg, @"abc"). Note that the "@" character is outside the quotes.

Second, if you have an object with a PROPERTY named "name" you may reference its value with either `[myObj name]` or `myObj.name`, and set it either with `[myObj setName:newValue];` or with `myObj.name = newValue;`.

If you have an NSString object you wish to print for diagnostic purposes, you can print it using `NSLog(@"Here is the string ->%@", theString);`.  The `%@` is a special Objective-C formatting code meaning "treat the next format parm as an object and invoke it's `description` method, then display that result".

(And if you're "just learning" Objective-C there's no reason to be mucking with `ivar_getName` and its ilk.  Functions like that are very rarely needed.)

Comment: 1: the "@" in my if condition not use for NSString it's the return of ivar_getTypeEncoding() (if @ is returned => an Object )

2: in variable "name" I set the name of attributes at any iteration by using ivar_getName()

I want to use getter like this ==> [obj name]  where name change value (for loop ) . But here the variable name is not interpreted :/

My goal is that the variable is interpreted by its value. if in my iiteration variable name is set to "ID" I want to have: [obj name] => [id obj] ...

Comment: @user2421041 - None of that was apparent in your initial question, before you edited it.  And, as I said, if you're "just learning" there are many more important things to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing an Objective-C string, use `NSLog`

```
NSLog(@" %@ ", [obj name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To print a string in objective-c you can use NSLog. The call looks like

```
NSLog(@"%@",[obj name]);
```

Comment: Thk, but it's not the purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite read your question right - but I think you want to dynamically fetch them.

See below for an example.

Dw.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface Frob : NSObject;
@property (strong) NSString * name, * bar, * fred;
@end
@implementation Frob
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Frob * frob = [[Frob alloc] init];
        frob.name = @"aName value";
        frob.bar = @"aBar value";
        frob.fred = @"aFred value";

        const char *lst[] = { "name", "bar", "fred" };
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(lst)/sizeof(char*); i++)
        {
            const char * nameStr = lst[i];

            SEL s = sel_getUid(nameStr);
            if (s) {
                NSString * val = [frob performSelector:s];
                NSLog(@"%s --> %@\n", nameStr, val);
                printf("%s --> %s", nameStr, [val UTF8String]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```